# What is the significance of using $compile in directive definition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Following code is similar to the one provided in [this](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-build-a-debug-directive) video by egghead.io` where he was building a directive for debugging.

```
app.directive('debug',function($compile){// injecting compiler
    return{ // DDO
        terminal:true,
        priority:1000,
        link:function($scope,$element){
            var clone = $element.clone();
            clone.removeAttr("debug");
            $element.addClass('highlight');
            var clonedElement = $compile(clone)($scope);
            $element.after(clonedElement);
        }
    };
});
```

My question is, what is the significance of using `$compile` to `compile` the `clone` and then adding `clonedElement` to the DOM? I tried to add(code given below) `clone` instead of `clonedElement` and it APPARENTLY does the same thing.

```
app.directive('debug',function($compile){// injecting compiler
    return{ // DDO
        terminal:true,
        priority:1000,
        link:function($scope,$element){
            var clone = $element.clone();
            clone.removeAttr("debug");
            $element.addClass('highlight');
            //var clonedElement = $compile(clone)($scope);
            $element.after(clone);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely to matter in this limited example, but the difference is that Angular is not considering that DOM element. If the DOM element were to have directives or bindings, they will not work because Angular has not been made aware of that element. `$compile` is what associates a new DOM element with Angular.

Be sure to read the [**documentation**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) for APIs you're unfamiliar with.